# Main method not found in class Test

Tags: java

> i have created a class Test and inside that class i am referring to a class
>   called string which is created by myself and it is showing me main method not found exeption

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = new String();
     s.hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're trying to set the string value to "hello"? However, as sam said, s.hello() is searching for a method `hello()` in the String class that does not exist. You would need to use `String s = "hello";`

Comment: i understood what you are trying to expalin,  but here i'm not trying to assign hello to s, rather String is a  class which is created by me and it's there in current directory where Test class is residing. so i just changed the string[] args to java.lang.String[] args and it worked ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've created a class called `String` (why?!), then the `main` method won't be found because the `main` method must accept an array of `java.lang.String`, yet you've given `String` a new meaning. Just do

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args){
     String s = new String();
     s.hello();
}
```

Comment: yes! you are right it worked. but now i've one another dought, 
since the classes are loaded by the classloaders, and while the classloading machanism is happening during the delegation , won't bootStrap classloader would have loaded String class, How did it take my own String class, as no two classes with same name can be loaded into jvm memory, so if bootstrap classloader has loaded the default String class initially, 
how is it loading my own String class again..?

Comment: @VijendarThakur You can have two classes with the same simple name (`String`) but fully qualified names would have to be different (`java.lang.String` is not the same as `your_package.String`.

Answer (score 0):

`String` api is not having the method hello. You should rather check the api for String, to get more hands on. Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: here i'm not trying to refer to default String class. i'm trying to call my own class String which is having method hello() and i've compiled and executed class Test by placing my own class String in classpath..  that's where i'm getting this problem.

Comment: Then you must use the full name your `String` class. I.e. `com.sample.String.hello ();`

Answer (score 0):

The signature of main must be public static void main (java.lang.String [] args). As you override String class,tyou have to explicitely use full name of jjava.lang.String class.